# Origine du « chapô » ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, terminologie

J'étais surpris de découvrir l'existence et l'usage du mot « chapô » ; je croyais que « chapeau » était l'unique mot désignant le texte précédant un contenu.

Avez-vous une idée de son origine ? Je ne trouve rien à ce sujet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapô existe dans le dictionnaire Livio (apk android hors ligne disponible ici : https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Livio&hl=en) mais l'éditeur de texte de Windows, par exemple, ne le reconnaît pas. Le lemme même est disponible [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chap%C3%B4). En revanche, ce mot n'existe pas dans les dictionnaires plus connus. Peut-être n'est-il pas un mot acceptable tel quel. Par exemple on ne le trouve pas dans le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chap%C3%B4) ni dans le
[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/rechercher?q=chap%C3%B4&l=francais&culture=).

Une définition complète du mot existe [ici](http://www.communication-interne.fr/definition/chapeau-ou-chapo/).
Sur ce sujet voir un article intéressant : [alafortunedumot.blogs](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/tag/chap%C3%B4).
Deux autres articles : [ici](https://www.ecrirepourleweb.com/rediger-chapeau-articles-web-methode/) et aussi [ici](https://redacteurweb.fr/chapeau-introductif-chapo/).

Enfin et surtout, voici le [Ngram du mot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chap%C3%B4&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchap%C3%B4%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre 2e lien !